# Add warning message to navButton in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When I click on a standard button (Add, Edit, Delete) on jqGrid, it displays a warning "Please, select row" if no selected rows.

How do I also add a warning message for my navButton?

I added button.

```
[{caption: 'text',
  title: 'text',
  buttonicon: 'ui-icon-myicon',
  onClickButton: checkSelectedRows,
  position: 'last'
}]
```

and I want use checkSelectedRows method for check is any row selected and display warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code could looks like the following

```
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    caption: 'text',
    title: 'text',
    buttonicon: 'ui-icon-newwin',
    position: 'last',
    onClickButton: function () {
        var selRow = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
        if (selRow) {
           alert("row is selected");
           // do your main code here
        } else {
            $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod_" + this.id, {toTop: true, jqm: true});
        }
    }
});
```